# How to do pattern searching in a text file using class in python

Tags: python

I am trying to search a pattern using Class.

I have a sample text file given. I have to find search a string ('Debug_logs') in each line of text file. 
Then I have to print date of searched line by using pattern, `(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)`

Without using the Class, I am able to do and getting perfect results.

But how to make it work with class and objects.

```
import re

class text_processing:

    def __init__(self,file_name):
        print ("File opened")
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.search_pat = 'DEBUG Facebook'


    def search(self):
        print ("in sreach function")
        for line in self.file_name:
            print (line)
            if self.search_pat in line:
                print (self.line)
                for i in self.search_pat:
                    print re.findall(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", self.search_pat)
                    break

def main():
    filename = 'sample1.txt'
    file_open = open(filename, "r")
    x = text_processing(file_open)
    x.search()
```

Comment: !!! stop using open(filename) - this code is typical example of forgetting to close file after using it!!!! there is a construct of with open(filename) as ...  that closes resources for you! also prefer opening file(taking resources) when you need that not in the main.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works for me, as long as you call main()

Comment: even if it works - it can be improved and also memory leaking bugs should be fixed - normally if you want to really use it

Comment: @DeltaMarine101 Yes, it not showing any error, but it is not going into for loop of search method.

Comment: @Drako can you give an example to improve this? you can change in my code and can post...

Comment: Sorry leaving, busy for next ~7-8h; search "python open with" if problems can return to this tomorrow

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output and the 'sample1.txt'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want it to do exactly, but I've fixed the issues with file opening and such (now the object is passed the file name, and the file is only opened when the search() function is called), and a few other things.

```
import re

class text_processing:

    def __init__(self,file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.search_pat = 'DEBUG Facebook'


    def search(self):
        print ("File opened")
        print ("in search function")
        with open(self.file_name, "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                print (line)
                if self.search_pat in line:
                    print (re.findall(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", line))


def main():
    filename = 'sample1.txt'
    x = text_processing(filename)
    x.search()

main()
```

Before you were searching for the pattern in `self.search_pat`, which is just the text 'DEBUG Facebook', so it wasn't finding anything. You were also looping over each character in 'DEBUG Facebook' and so you redundantly searched 14 times when `re.findall` already loops through and finds all occurrences.

I hope I understood what you were trying to achieve correctly and helped you :)